# Relation/Sort not working in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following relation in my rails app:

genre
 - has many - authors

authors - belong to genre and has many books

books - belongs to authors and belongs to users

(users can add books to the db)

in my controller I have:

```
@books=current_user.books(:include => [:author => :genre], :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

While I am able to use the @books variable in my views - nothing is done correctly (i.e. its not showing me only books added by that user, and its not descending by created_at)...

any ideas?

--

### Also I'm using clearance for the user auth, so current_user without the @ in the controller seems to work fine

Actually, I think the relation is working, only the sort might not be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which created_at do you want to sort on? When you're engaging a join, it's usually safer to be specific:

```
@books = current_user.books(..., :order => 'books.created_at DESC')
```

The other thing you can do is sort it in the client which may be faster than having the RDBMS do it if you're not paginating:

```
@books = current_user.books(...).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
```

If you're paginating these results you will need to sort in the query, there's no way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tadman! the first thing didn't seem to work - but the second did? I'm not using pagination right now - but I was planning on adding it soon. 

In the first one it seems like its just being ignored, I don't really understand the syntax though

Comment: You probably have a default order on your scope that is getting blended in. If you look at your log you might see something like: "ORDER BY created_at, books.created_at DESC" where the order you've requested is merely appended to, and does not replace, the default. What query are you getting when you run the non-working line?

Comment: Hey Tadman,

So I tried adding ajax pagination - but ran into enough errors that I think I'll stick with the second solution you posted for now. But if I decide to go back I'll have to fix the default! Thanks again for the help!